# why can not regular express pattern "\r","\n","\s","[\n\r]" hit this break row?

Tags: regex

Can anyone tell me why regular express can not match ",2336" after ",2336,"

phrase:

```
ratio：71%  
win：2336,2367,23363626,2336,2336  
877  
lose：2336
```

tried pattern:

```
(：|,)2336(,|\s|$)  
(：|,)2336(,|\n|$)  
(：|,)2336(,|\r|$)  
(：|,)2336(,|[\n\r]|$)
```

http://regexr.com/3fgb7

Comment: Because in all your variants the comma is compulsory. Something like `(：|,)2336(|,\s|$)` will allow for the last `2336` to be matched.

Comment: Because it matched the previous ",2336,", so the next character is 2, and not `(：|,)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the comma between the two instances of `2336` has been already consumed by the previous match, therefore it can't match again, but your regex demands that.

You can fix that by changing your second group to a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(：|,)2336(?=[,\s]|$)
```